# SQL Compact Edition 3.0 -> 3.5 Confused why 3.5 is required now

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-ce

I have a .NET 2.0 winforms application that was built in vs2005. It deployed and used SQL CE 3.0 behind the scenes. All was good, and working.

Then we decided we wanted to make some changes to the winform application installer portion, so we moved everything to Visual studio 2010, leaving it targeted for the .NET 2.0 clr. We made some project changes, got the installer working, etc.

But now clean installs that used to require the 3.0 CE support files, don't work, and I get a message about a version mismatch. Installing the 3.5 CE base, fixes this, I just don't understand why/what changed it to be forced to this version.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Is it because, VS2010 had installed 3.5, and I've opened the project and run it with 3.5 accessing the SDF db file? and inadvertently 'converted' it to 3.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS 2010 was the issue. It had installed the 3.5 version of CE. Using the 3.5 support files worked just fine.